# Const Char* test() return String.c_Str() don't work properly

Tags: char, constants

I m confused about this issue:

```
Const Char* Test() {
    String a = "anything";
    Return a.c_str();
}

Void Main() {
    Cout << Test(); // returns crap!
}
```

Anybody got an idea what i don't think of?
This page is Not iPhone optimized ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with allocating the string on heap:

```
string *a=new string("anything");
return (*a).c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

`String a` is in automatic memory and it is destroyed when you return from `Test()`, so memory allocated for `c_str` is freed as well

Answer (score 1):

C language is stack based.
String a in function Test() is allocated in stack.

```
const Char* Test() {
   std::string a = "anything";  // Allocated in stack based
   return a.c_str(); // A is freeing for return.
}

Void Main() {
    std::cout << Test(); // returns crap!
}
```

---

```
const char* Test(std::string *a) {
   *a = "anything";
   return a->c_str();
}

Void Main() {
    std::string a;
    std::cout << Test(&a);
}
```

---

OR

```
const Char* Test() {
   **static** std::string a = "anything";  // Allocated in data memory
   return a.c_str(); // data memory freed when application terminating.
}

Void Main() {
    std::cout << Test();
}
```